# Office Web Components 11 in SP2010

Tags: development, web-part, deployment

Can somebody confirm me is it possible to use owc 11 in SharePoint 2010?!
I use owc chart control, and in my other project(asp.net web app) I can use owc without problems. In SP 2010 I can build and deploy SP solution with same functionality (as in asp.net project) placed in my web part, but after I  start to use my web part (e.g. button click should start chart creation) i get this message:

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0002E55D-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0002E55D-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few days of easy studying about this problem conclusion is: 
It's not possible to host owc 11 in x64 application pool which means it's not possible to host owc11 in SharePoint 2010.

What is possible:

1. create custom (separated) WCF service (x86) who use owc11 (in my case that were owc chart classes)
2. create http handler (in SP layouts folder) which calling wcf and parsing response
3. create some asp.net control (in e.g. some web part) which than bind to http handler

And that's it.

Comment: And additional link (to be aware of):
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317316/